# If condition with or in python

Tags: python-3.x

If i have list containing Null empty string and some value then i can i use condition for both empty and value.In my case if i am using to check "89" and "Null" it is not processing message for value instead shows empty value can not processed.Value should be processed for value and not for Null condition.

```
payload=[{'id': 'Room1',
'pressure': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': 'Null'},
`'temperature':{'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': '89`'},
'type': 'RoomTest'}]

attrs=['temperature','pressure']
x=(len(payload))
for i in range(x):
for j in attrs:
        y=payload[i][j]['value']
        print(y)
        for item in y:
            print(item)
            if item is ["Null", ""]:
               print("empty value can not processed")
            if item is not["Null",""]:
               print("successfully processed for value")
```

I have also tried using "any" but still same result.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: With the code you show, what is printed? What did you expect to be printed? Also  note that `" "` is not the same as `""`.

Comment: for value "89" it should print msg "successfully processed for value" and for "Null' or empty string "empty value can not processed"

Comment: So you want to iterate over each value in the list, and check them individually? Because right now you just check for `"Null"` or `" "` existence in the list.

Comment: yes i want to check for every value if value comes "89" it should print msg successfull and in case its null or empty it should print message not successfull,Eg, i m having both null and "89" so it should show both messages but not coming favourable outcome in above case

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
payload=[{'id': 'Room1',
'pressure': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': 'Null'},
'temperature':{'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': '89'},
'type': 'RoomTest'}]

attrs=['temperature','pressure']
for item in payload:
  for attr in attrs:
    value = item[attr]['value']
    if value in ["Null", ""]:
        print("empty value can not processed")
    else:
        print("successfully processed for value")
```

Comment: i have edited above code can u pls tell me what i am missing in it

Comment: Thanks @MjZac, can u pls tell me how to remove value "Null" or "" after this condition " if value in ["Null", ""]: " , I have tried y.pop(Null)

Comment: What do you want to be deleted? the whole `'pressure': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': 'Null'}` entry or just `'value': 'Null'` ?

Comment: Just value Null and in my case when i use "Null" in if condition it throws error Cannot cast 'NULL' to type float

Comment: You can do something like `del item[attr]['value']` in the `if` statement to delete `'value': 'Null'` entry in a dict.